# Is this considered a curried function?

Tags: functional-programming, sml, currying

I'm still a bit confused about currying -

I've got an implementation of map in SML, is this considered as a curried function?

```
fun mymap f xs = List.foldr (fn (x, l) => (f x)::l) [] xs;
```

Or do I need to be more explicit about enforcing the single parameter passing?

```
fun mymap f = (fn xs => List.foldr (fn (x, l) => (f x)::l) [] xs);
```

Comment: yes it is, in fact former is exactly the same as latter (after desugaring)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, both functions are curried.  In fact, the first function is shorthand for the second function.

Answer (score 2):

Adam already answered this, but I want to teach you to fish.

Each time you type a function into an SML interpreter, you'll get a response with the function's type signature.  Here's the first one:

```
- fun mymap f xs = List.foldr (fn (x, l) => (f x)::l) [] xs;
val mymap = fn : ('a -> 'b) -> 'a list -> 'b list
```

And here's the second one:

```
- fun mymap f = (fn xs => List.foldr (fn (x, l) => (f x)::l) [] xs);
val mymap = fn : ('a -> 'b) -> 'a list -> 'b list
```

The first thing we notice is they have the same type signature, which is consistent with the claim that the second is a desugared form of the first.

According to the signature, `mymap` takes a function which maps from one type to another.  Let's experiment using `Int.toString`:

```
- mymap Int.toString;
val it = fn : int list -> string list
```

We've just done a partial application of the `mymap` function, which is only possible because `mymap` is a curried function.

For contrast, let's see what happens with a version of `mymap` that isn't curried.

```
- fun mymapUncurried (f,xs) = List.foldr (fn (x, l) => (f x)::l) [] xs;
val mymapUncurried = fn : ('a -> 'b) * 'a list -> 'b list
```

This is the same as your first function, except the arguments are enclosed in a tuple.  As a result, the type signature is also different (see the `*`?).  `mymapUncurried` takes a 2-tuple whose first element has type `('a -> 'b)` and whose second argument has type `'a list`.  Now partial application doesn't work:

```
- mymapUncurried Int.toString;
stdIn:9.1-9.28 Error: operator and operand don't agree [tycon mismatch]
  operator domain: ('Z -> 'Y) * 'Z list
  operand:         int -> string
  in expression:
    mymapUncurried Int.toString
```

However, full application does work.  Just don't forget to pass the arguments as a tuple:

```
- mymapUncurried (Int.toString, [1,2,3]);
val it = ["1","2","3"] : string list
```